# How can set more than one role for user to give many permissions

Tags: laravel, permissions

I create a website.
In this,I created some packages (example- movie package)
User can buy this packages.
I created permission to see this movies for this users when they buy one package.
But if user want to buy next package,example book packages.,I need to permit to view him both two packages.

I created this permission by spatie package.
In this, I created roles for user.
Movie role member can view movie.

I want to know is can I set one user more than one role.
I already tried ,cannot.

If I want to permit this user to view both packages,how can I do.

Any suggestion I hope here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean if you can set more than one role to a model? Yes you can. It is in [Spatie's Laravel Permission readme](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#usage):

> #### Using permissions via roles
>
> A role can be assigned to any user:
>
> ```php
> $user->assignRole('writer');
>
> // You can also assign multiple roles at once
> $user->assignRole('writer', 'admin');
> // or as an array
> $user->assignRole(['writer', 'admin']);
> ```
>
> A role can be removed from a user:
>
> ```php
> $user->removeRole('writer');
> ```
>
> Roles can also be synced:
>
> ```php
> // All current roles will be removed from the user and replaced by the array given
> $user->syncRoles(['writer', 'admin']);
> ```

So, to assign `movie` and also `book` permissions to a user you can do:

```php
$user = App\User::find(1); // get the user
$user->assignRole(['movie', 'book']); // assigning roles
```

In case the user already has a role, try the sync method. This will delete all previous roles and attach the specified ones:

```php
$user = App\User::find(1); // get the user
$user->syncRoles(['movie', 'book']); // syncing roles
```

You can also check it out in the Spatie tests: [it_can_assign_multiple_roles_at_once()](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/tests/HasRolesTest.php#L95)

Comment: HCK thanks bro.You are genious expert.I really thank.

Comment: @linlin you doesn't need to be an expert to do this mate, just pay attention to the documentation. That's all. Have a nice day.

Comment: @linlin btw, if this was helpful you can mark the question as answered.